# Server design: Send UDP packet for SSLTCP wakeup?

Tags: ssl, tcp, udp

I have a server that at the minute that creates a new thread for each client connecting securely. If I use a thread pool this will mean that I will have a finite number of clients at once. However this means that I can not be listening on ports for all clients.

My idea is to have the client send a UDP packet with some ID linked to there connection so that they can re-establish the connect rather than lock up a thread for 10-60 seconds (server will keep the SSLsockets in memory). *Is that a good way to solve the problem?* - I don't see any security security vulnerabilities.

The server is java and the client is C++ not that effects the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense. If the client wants to reconnect it should just open a new socket. You are positing at least one extra thread to listen to the UDP port and then ... what? It still has to use the thread pool to handle that client, if that is your self-imposed constraint, or else start a new thread, in which case you may as well not have had the thread pool constraint in the first place.

> However this means I cannot be listening on ports for all clients.

No it doesn't. It just means that some clients will get delayed service while the thread pool is full, and a very few clients will get connection failure while the backlog queue is full. It doesn't impair your ability to *listen* for clients at all.

Comment: That means that I will be cycling connections then checking if there are any bytes to read?

Comment: Plus available() on SSL socket stream returns 0 in all cases.. What do you suggest? It seams that you can only read an SSL socket stream by locking.  So I could make the client send a message to say that they are done with requests for a short while. Then when a worker thread comes back to that client and it could message the client(constantly blocking maybe) to see if they have any requests. or  Is there away to set a timeout on the inputsteams read?

Comment: looking in to set socket timeout.

Comment: @Andrew No, it doesn't mean that, so your subsequent questions about available() are irrelevant. It means you will be blocking in read() methods, which can have a timeout. I don't know why you think the client needs to tell the server it won't be telling the server anything for a while. Maybe you need to think about a client-side thread pool.

Comment: Ok I am using the socket timeout exception and then catching that and putting the client object back on a queue for the pool

Comment: Should timeout time be dynamic. i.e based on size of the queue of clients  that are not been handled by workers? Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Andrew To be honest I think you are solving a non-problem here. The real issue is the size of the thread pool. Make it bigger! Ditto the listen backlog. The read timeout is basically like an HTTP KEEPALIVE timeout, which is typically 10-15 seconds. I would keep it as short as practical, and constant. Life is hard enough already ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What if the only port you have say TCP/443 (HTTPS)? What if UDP is firewalled (very much possible)? In other words, you should NOT introduce UDP into this picture.

Even in thread-pool scenario, you can still know the difference between multiple clients who connected to the same server port.

Typical solution for this is to create set of sockets you are going to be watching for at once (in one thread) - in C/C++ it is typically done using `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll()`, and in Java you can use `java.nio`.

This way, if any client(s) have something to say to you as a server, your `select` loop will instantly notice that, serve these clients and go back to `select()`, which consumes very little (effectively 0) CPU usage.

This is an example how to do [select loop in C](http://www.tenouk.com/Module41.html) and similar example [in Java](http://www.cordinc.com/blog/2010/08/java-nio-server-example.html).

Comment: Thanks i'll have I read through that. Its a master server for a game so I will be using UDP for the servers but avoiding it for the master server would be ideal. Thanks again.

Comment: I am struggling to understand how I can use this with SSLServerSocket since it seems to replace the conventional ServerSocket.

Comment: It does not replace it, it inherits from it. So, it has same basic methods and should still work with java.nio, but this is probably not as easy you want to it to be. This is probably [good reading](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/11/03/ssl-nio.html) for you

Comment: I just had a skim through and it all looked promising up uptil the last section where I would have to start hacking at my c++/objectiveC clients were both nightmares to setup blocking even. I think I might go for the bodge job now otherwise ill end up getting hung up and ruining my dissertation.

Comment: I don't think your clients have to know anything about server implementation (blocking or not). If your client can talk SSLTCP now, it should not have to be rewritten

Comment: @mvp SSLServerSocket won't work with non-blocking NIO, and neither will ServerSocket for that matter.